# What to use as NSCoder to initialize a View?

Tags: swift, nscoder

Hey guys I created a new custom View Class and now I want to build a instance of it, I initialized it with the following code:

```
required init?(coder aCoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aCoder)
           tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                           target: self, action: #selector(handleBarTap))
           addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
       }

       deinit {
           removeGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
       }
```

And this is the instance, but what can I use as coder?

```
lazy var chartView = TutorialChartView(coder: )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say View, do you mean UIView? The problem is that that's the wrong initializer. `init(coder:)` is not something you call; it's a process initiated by the storyboard when there is one of these things in the storyboard and you load that view controller.

The code UIView designated initializer is `init(frame:)`. Implement that and call it, and you're all set.

(You may *also* have to provide an implementation of `init(coder:)` but it should just throw a `fatalError`, because you do not expect to be called this way.)

Answer (score 0):

You should cannot use `coder` as initializer for creating class, use frame instead, here is your code written in frame-style initializing.

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleBarTap))
    addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Here is how you use it:

```
 lazy var chartView = TutorialChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
```